# Is there some way of running tasks on suspended apps with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm creating an app and I would like to create a method that could run every 10 seconds when the app isn't open.

I'm using expo. I tried to use react-native-background-timer, but it doesn't work since i would need to link the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way.

Expo is a limited way to create React Native Apps that doesn't allow you to do complex things like this.

To try to do what you want you should create a new Project with `react-native init "Name Project"`

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/task-manager/ - as of April of this year, they've begun supporting doing some limited actions [Background Fetch](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/sdk/background-fetch/) could be of use to you.

But as noted above, if you really need more than this functionality, you'll want to eject and get off expo.